# Adding reactive FormGroup dynamically moves others behind above elements

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angluar 6 reactive forms and am adding form groups dynamically. However the styling is totally wrong and I have no clue, what the problem could be (See image).
It's a mix of Angular Material (`mat-grid-list, mat-grid-tile, mat-list, mat-list-item`) and angluar flex-layout.
The list elements seem centered, but it is nowhere set to centered.

Please excuse that I don't have a code example, but it would be just way to much work to try to get it into JSfiddle.

I would just like to hear some opinions and if others have experienced the same issue. If I find an answer I will post it here myself.

[image: gif of wrong behavior when adding a groupform dynamically]

Comment: can give an example at stackblitz,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material.     To be able to help you?

Comment: it's look like your "row" has a negative margin or your line-height must be bigger. sorry, I can't help more

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple. Never put a `<mat-list>` into a `<mat-grid-list>`! They are two seperate concepts. Mat-grid-list is for layouts with columns and mat-list is only for layout with rows and only one column.